# How to add android permission editing codename one properties

Tags: codenameone, android-permissions

I'm using some specific android libraries and i need to add the following permission:

I also tried to add it in my project properties:

Key: `android.xpermissions`

value:

```
<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

But when i start the application i got this error message:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings
>   requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

I tried on android 4.3 and on android 5.0.1. 
Am i doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add this in the build hints section or did you edit the `codenameone_settings.properties` directly?

Notice that you should do the former as the entry in the `codenameone_settings.properties` includes a prefix and needs to escape some of the values here.

The permission syntax you used is incorrect as it only applies to newer versions of android (notice the -sdk-k) you need to use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```